# Can I use labels while creating Generators in ArgoCD ApplicationSet's for targeting deploying Applications in specific clusters

Tags: devops, argocd, argo, gitops

I have a single Git repo with multiple folders (with K8s manifests) and I got 4 K8s clusters where manifests in a specific folder from Git repo needs to be deployed on a specific K8s cluster.

I figured a List generator can be sufficed but if I can use a Git generator or Matrix Generator (Mix of List & Git Generators), can I provide labels in the ApplicationSet to target my manifests in a specific Git folder to deploy on a specific K8s Cluster?

Comment: Could you maybe describe in YAML what you'd like to be able to do? I'm not sure to see where and how labels would be used?